# Model static::creating canceling not work properly

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I am using Laravel, Livewire, FilamentPHP.

In my model i have

```
protected static function boot(): void
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $uuid = Uuid::uuid4();

            $reservation = Reservation::where('reservation_date', now()->format("Y-m-d"))->where('user_id', $model->user_id)->first();
            if (!$reservation?->id) {
                Notification::make()->title("This user doesn't have a reservation.")->danger()->send();
                return false;
            }
            $model->reservation_id = $reservation->id;
            return false;

            $model->order_uuid = $uuid->toString();
        });
    }
```

and then when i change my code block to ->

```
protected static function boot(): void
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $uuid = Uuid::uuid4();

            $reservation = Reservation::where('reservation_date', now()->format("Y-m-d"))->where('user_id', $model->user_id)->first();
            if (!$reservation?->id) {
                Notification::make()->title("This user doesn't have a reservation.")->danger()->send();
                return false;
            } else {
                $model->reservation_id = $reservation->id;
                $model->order_uuid = $uuid->toString();
            }

        });
    }
```

then this time it throw me->  Missing required parameter for [Route: filament.admin.resources.orders.edit] [URI: admin/orders/{record}/edit] [Missing parameter: record]. error.

I expect whenever there is no $reservation->id it will send a notification and it will stop saving it. However in the reality it returns me:

- 404 Not Found Page ('I wish it was just sending the notificaiton what i want instead of returning this page')
- After refreshing the page manually it show 2 notification -> Model Created Notification & This user doesn't have a reservation Notification.

what i am doing wrong here? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not put the logic inside the model event, but instead in a function which check if the reservation exists :

```php
$reservation = Reservation::where('reservation_date', now()->format("Y-m-d"))->where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
            if (!$reservation) {
                Notification::make()->title("This user doesn't have a reservation.")->danger()->send();
            } else {  
                // create your object 
            }
```

You Model shouldn't handle the validation logic of it's creation